# How can tar backup access timestamps

Tags: tar

How can tar backup file access timestamps so it is included somewhere in the *.tar file? I couldn't find this in the docs, the closest was `--atime-preserve`, which preserves access times on the source file system, but says nothing about what goes into the tar file.

Comment: Are you asking if/how you can timestamp a tar backup or just a yes it can, no it can't answer?

Comment: I've tried to clear things up, I would like an example if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't. The access time doesn't get stored in the [file headers](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man4/tar.4.asp).